# How a thread which is blocked while trying to mutex_lock get to know that the lock is released by another thread?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, synchronization, mutex

In Linux, I have a scenario where two threads execute a critical section, one acquires the lock (thread A) and the other(thread B) will wait for the lock. Later threadA releases the mutex lock. I am trying to understand how threadB will be moved to the running state and acquire the lock? How threadB(or operating system) knows that the lock is released by threadA?

I have a theory, please correct if I am wrong. threadB enters TASK_INTERRUPTABLE (blocked at the mutex and so waiting) state and it receives signal when threadA unlocks the mutex so it comes back to the running queue(TASK_RUNNING).

Answer (score 1):

The Linux mutex struct keeps track of the current owner of the mutex (if any):

```c
struct mutex {
    atomic_long_t       owner;
    // ...
```

There's also a struct to keep track of what other tasks are waiting on a mutex:

```c
/*
 * This is the control structure for tasks blocked on mutex,
 * which resides on the blocked task's kernel stack:
 */
struct mutex_waiter {
    struct list_head    list;
    struct task_struct  *task;
    struct ww_acquire_ctx   *ww_ctx;
#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_MUTEXES
    void            *magic;
#endif
};
```

Simplifying quite a bit, when you unlock a mutex, the kernel looks at what other tasks are waiting on that mutex. It picks one of them to become the owner, sets the mutex's owner field to refer to the selected task, and removes that task from the list of tasks waiting for the mutex. At that point, there's at least a good chance that task has become un-blocked, in which case it'll be ready to run once it's unblocked. At that point, it's up to the scheduler to decide when to run it.

### Optimization

Since mutexes are used a lot, and they get locked and unlocked quite a bit, they use some optimization to help speed. For example, consider the following:

```c
/*
 * @owner: contains: 'struct task_struct *' to the current lock owner,
 * NULL means not owned. Since task_struct pointers are aligned at
 * at least L1_CACHE_BYTES, we have low bits to store extra state.
 *
 * Bit0 indicates a non-empty waiter list; unlock must issue a wakeup.
 * Bit1 indicates unlock needs to hand the lock to the top-waiter
 * Bit2 indicates handoff has been done and we're waiting for pickup.
 */
#define MUTEX_FLAG_WAITERS  0x01
#define MUTEX_FLAG_HANDOFF  0x02
#define MUTEX_FLAG_PICKUP   0x04

#define MUTEX_FLAGS     0x07
```

So, when you ask the kernel to unlock a mutex, it can "glance" at one bit in the owner pointer to figure out whether this is a "simple" case (nobody's waiting on the mutex, so just mark it as unlocked, and off we go), or a more complex one (at least one task is waiting on the mutex, so a task needs to be selected to be unblocked, and be marked as the new owner of the mutex.

### References

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/mutex.h
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/locking/mutex.c

#### Disclaimer

The code extracts above are (I believe) current as I write this answer. But as noted above, mutexes get used a lot. If you look at the code for a mutex 5 or 10 years from now, chances are you'll find that somebody has done some work on optimizing the code, so it may not precisely match what I've quoted above. Most of the concepts are likely to remain similar, but changes in details (especially the optimizations) are to be expected.